# Read all methode attributes using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, custom-attributes

I'm trying to read all attributes of a methode which contains more than one attribute of the same type like:

```
[field(Feld = "x86", Index = 1)]
[field(Feld = "x93", Index = 2)]
...
[field(Feld = "x107", Index = 9)]
public string Methodename() {}
```

Reading the Attribute like:

```
Attribute mAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute
                  (methodInfo, typeof (fieldAttribute), false) as fieldAttribute;
```

This throwing an [AmbiguousMatchException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ambiguousmatchexception.aspx). How do i read more than one attribute?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130871.aspx) instead of GetCustomAttribute :)

For example:

```
Attribute[] attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes
              (methodInfo, typeof (fieldAttribute), false);
```

Comment: Ohh man i gota be blind! i didnt even look for the same methode name in plural. Thank you